# Position of a scheme (figure) at a specific point in the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have this scheme code

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (s1) at (0.4,0) {Market risk};
    \node[draw] (s2) at (-5.3,-2) {Interest rate};
    \node[draw] (s3) at (-3,-2) {Equity};
    \node[draw] (s4) at (-1,-2) {Property};
    \node[draw] (s5) at (1,-2) {Spread};
    \node[draw] (s6) at (3,-2) {Currency};
    \node[draw] (s7) at (5.7,-2) {Concentration};

    \path
    (s1) edge[-, >=latex'] (s2)
    (s1) edge[-, >=latex'] (s3)
    (s1) edge[-, >=latex'] (s4)
    (s1) edge[-, >=latex'] (s5)
    (s1) edge[-, >=latex'] (s6)
    (s1) edge[-, >=latex'] (s7)    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Market risk module and respective sub-modules.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

and I want this scheme to appear after a text and it's appearing in the start of the sheet could you give some help please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure is a float. This means that it's positioning is not always where you put it in the code, but where (La)TeX deems it best (depending on the parameters you fed it).

You might solve your issue by writing

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
```

or

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

For a detailed answer see this post here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)